# Vue Volar template autocomplete/intellisense not working with defineComponent in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, volar

## Problem

I cant get syntax highlighting/intellisense to work with volar when using defineComponent.
I have:

- installed TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)
- installed Vue Language Features (Volar)
- setup take over mode

I've added

```js
"vueCompilerOptions": {
    "optionsWrapper": [
      "(await import('vue')).defineComponent(",
      ")"
    ],
```

to my tsconfig.

### Example

I have a component FooComponent:

```js
<template lang="pug">
div(:id="test.foo.bar")
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

    const test = {
      foo: {
        bar: "test",
      },
    };

    return { test };
  },
});
</script>
```

Autocomplete works inside of the defineComponent block:

(i hover over `test` in `defineComponent` and it shows the object structure)

[image: autcomplete working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMVhA.png)

but not inside of the template:

(i try to autocomplete `test.foo.` but `bar` is not suggested)

[image: autocomplete not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUka4.png)

Hovering over `test` doesnt even show anything.

I have tried everything at this point, i cant get this to work.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the tsconfig file as follows

```
"vueCompilerOptions": {
   "target": 2.7, // or 3 (vue version in use)
   "extensions": [
    ".vue"
   ]
}
```